# Добавления нового пользователя в программу

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Имеется программа, в ней есть авторизация (ввод логина и пароля). Необходимо сделать, чтобы меню с добавлением/удалением нового пользователя была только у администратора, а у других новых пользователей не было добавления. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это реализовать? Новую форму для администратора и пользователя делать не варинт!

Comment: @ldimkol, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: У меня существует сама программа, просто не могу понять как сделать для каждого пользователя программы разные права в программе!

Comment: [Как правильно задавать вопросы][1]


  [1]: http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вам надо разграничить пользователей по правам доступа. К примеру:

```
ID   NAME   ROLE  
-----------------
1    Вася   0  
2    Петя   0  
3    Админ  1
```

При авторизации пользователя Вам надо считывать его роль и хранить её на протяжении всей работы приложения. И в нужный момент делать простую проверку и давать/ограничивать доступ к определенным функциям приложения.

---

У Вас же есть какая-то база данных, где хранятся пользователи?  Просто не зная, как у вас это все реализовано, тяжело дать развернутый ответ.